# Proof of a property of the complex inversion

Tags: complex-analysis

> Consider the map $k: \mathbb C^* \to\mathbb C^*$ defined as $k(z) = 1/z $. Prove that any line in the complex plane not passing through the origin is mapped to a circular line that passes through the origin. (No assumptions are made about the center of the circle.)

Comment: "Circular line"? Like what, say?

Comment: Is $\mathbb{C}^*\equiv\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{Re}{\mathrm{Re}}
\DeclareMathOperator{Im}{\mathrm{Im}}$Let $z=x+iy$: the equation of a line in the complex plane is $y=ax+b$ (with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$) from which you get
\begin{align}
\Im(z)-a\Re(z)-b&=0\\
-\Re(iz)-a\Re(z)-b&=0\\
\Re[(a+i)z]+b&=0\\
\frac{a+i}2z+\frac{a-i}2\bar{z}+b&=0.
\end{align}
Now if you substitute $w=k(z)=\frac1{z}$ you get
\begin{align}
\frac{a+i}2\frac1{w}+\frac{a-i}2\frac1{\bar{w}}+b&=0\\
\frac{a+i}2\bar{w}+\frac{a-i}2w+bw\bar{w}&=0\\
\frac{a+i}{2b}\bar{w}+\frac{a-i}{2b}w+w\bar{w}&=0
\end{align}
multiplying by $w\bar{w}$ and dividing by $b$ ($\ne 0$ by hypothesis).
Compare it with the equation of a circle of centre $c$ and radius $r$
\begin{align}
\lvert w-c\rvert&=r\\
(w-c)(\overline{w-c})&=r^2\\
w\bar{w}-c\bar{w}-\bar{c}w+\lvert c\rvert^2&=r^2
\end{align}
and you see that the equation above describes a circle centred in $-\frac{a+i}{2b}$ with radius $\bigl\lvert\frac{a+i}{2b}\bigr\rvert$, so it includes the origin.